# javascript undefined, when I just logged it

Tags: javascript

So I just posted a Q about a nested date object and got a speedy answer, felt kinda silly, it was obvious, but no sooner did I get one correct response when something else throw an undefined error.

I'm inside a method call that "finds" a key, and then I want to use the data in that key for other things

This :

```
Coupon.findKey( req.params._key, (err, key) => {

    if ( err ) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }

    console.log('---------- key '+key+'----------');

});
```

Gives me this:

```
---------- key { _id: 5a72c5cbe617796370219fb3, token: 'mWJhRlytyjaxztWfsP6tpH7PccEpSfkemZqyt9pf26e4fI1b32e5Qun8LfLKmkhXMytFtB7QYHHLUgGV0V7AwUB055Cp78Old2IrBHlmgDDFl6qYxe05cgTFLzjmzuAZ', user_id: 5a72c5cbe617796370219fb2, type: 'registration', __v: 0, date: { redeemed: null, issued: 2018-02-01T07:46:19.449Z } }----------
```

clearly - Coupon.findKey() returned an object. That object "appears" to have _id and user_id available.

However if I do this

```
Coupon.findKey( req.params._key, (err, key) => {

    if ( err ) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }

    console.log('---------- key '+ key._id +'----------');

});
```

I get

```
---------- key undefined----------
```

WHAT THE HECK. Javascript, you break my will...

Help anyone....

And my frustration mounts
[mongoose not returning a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574699/mongoose-not-returning-a-record)

Comment: Just print  `typeof key` and tell us what you received.

Comment: typeof key  is object

Comment: @jpmyob: Can you please `console.log(JSON.stringify(key))`?

Comment: @Cerbrus, maybe `JSON.parse`

Comment: console.log('---------- key '+ key +'----')
and console.log('---------- key '+ key._id + '----') not the same

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut: No. `key` isn't a string. OP replied that the `typeof` is `object`

Comment: JSON.stringify give me this  [{"_id":"5a72c5cbe617796370219fb3","key":"mWJhRlytyjaxztWfsP6tpH7PccEpSfkemZqyt9pf26e4fI1b32e5Qun8LfLKmkhXMytFtB7QYHHLUgGV0V7AwUB055Cp78Old2IrBHlmgDDFl6qYxe05cgTFLzjmzuAZ","user_id":"5a72c5cbe617796370219fb2","type":"registration","__v":0,"date":{"redeemed":null,"issued":"2018-02-01T07:46:19.449Z"}}]

Comment: Then use indexes in order to access elements

Comment: `key` seems to be an array. Try `key[0]._id`

Comment: and JSON.parse give me this   Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 2

Comment: @jpmyob: You don't need to `parse` it. It's not a JSON string. I requested the `stringify` to get a clear picture of the variable's structure.

Comment: @Cerbrus - thx. It's odd, because I had the [0] before (my other post references in question) but when i implemented THAT solution my response with the [0] thru the undefined error.... which is why I cam e here frustrated, - now...console.log(key) shows the [] array brackets, and key[0]._id works. I appreciate the help - but it seems the behavior is unstable, so I'm still frustrated, but appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` seems to be an array.

Get the first entry from that array: `key[0]._id`

`key[0]` is:

```
{
    "_id": "5a72c5cbe617796370219fb3",
    "key": "mWJhRlytyjaxztWfsP6tpH7PccEpSfkemZqyt9pf26e4fI1b32e5Qun8LfLKmkhXMytFtB7QYHHLUgGV0V7AwUB055Cp78Old2IrBHlmgDDFl6qYxe05cgTFLzjmzuAZ",
    "user_id": "5a72c5cbe617796370219fb2",
    "type": "registration",
    "__v": 0,
    "date": {
        "redeemed": null,
        "issued": "2018-02-01T07:46:19.449Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked this for the answer - but as I mentioned above, the behavior seems erratic. I'll have to remember the stringify trick, I trusted the type of...

Comment: Well, my saga continues... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574699/mongoose-not-returning-a-record